# How to add classes to a ultrawebgrid?

Tags: .net, webforms, infragistics

I need to add a class to the table in a ultrawebgrid

I have worked out you can add a RowStyle or a CellStyle but what about a tableStyle??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DisplayLayout.FrameStyle will allow you to set a style on the frame of the control and you could use this.  The style inheritance may be of interest to you as well:
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=WebGrid_Style_Inheritance.html